# Need to Extract only Date from HTML format file to XLSx using Perl

Tags: perl

Kindly Help me in extracting only date from the HTML format to XLSX format using Perl.

In HTML format the date is having with time in the format of "2005-08-16 15:23:13.933"

I want to extract it as 2005-08-16.

This is what I have written so far

```
# General format date

my $date_format = $workbook->add_format();
$date_format->set_align('left');
$date_format->set_num_format('mm/dd/yyyy');

if ( $col_format ) {

    print "Col Type : $col_format\n";

    if ( $col_format eq "date_format2" ) {
        $date_format->set_num_format('mm/dd/yyyy');
    }
    else {
        $date_format->set_num_format('mm/dd/yyyy');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show some work. What have you tried?

Comment: # General format date

my $date_format = $workbook->add_format();

$date_format->set_align('left');
$date_format->set_num_format('mm/dd/yyyy');

if ($col_format) {

 print "Col Type    : $col_format\n";


  if ($col_format eq "date_format2") {

   $date_format->set_num_format('mm/dd/yyyy');
             
      }else{

   $date_format->set_num_format('mm/dd/yyyy');

      }

   }

Comment: Please show the html and  script in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have given a sample code which converts the cell format. It would be better if you share the HTML and the code you are trying to achieve.

```
$worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$date_format = $workbook->add_format();
$date_format->set_num_format('mm/dd/yy');
$worksheet->write(0,  0, 36892.521, $date_format);
```